# Why isn't my animation not waiting for an eventlistener before moving on?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

```
    var playGraph = new Chart();
var playPart1 = new Part1();
var playPart2 = new Part2();
var playPart3 = new Part3(); 

addChild(playGraph);
playGraph.gotoAndPlay(1);
var s1:SoundOne = new SoundOne();
s1.play();

playGraph.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteGraph); 
playPart1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompletePart1); 
playPart2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompletePart2); 

function onCompleteGraph(evt:Event):void
{
    playPart1.x = 370;
    playPart1.y = 190;
    addChild(playPart1);
    playPart1.gotoAndPlay(1);
}


function onCompletePart1(evt:Event):void
{

    playPart2.x = 100;
    playPart2.y = 100;
    addChild(playPart2);
    playPart2.gotoAndPlay(1);
    var s2:Sound2 = new Sound2();
    s2.play();

}

function onCompletePart2(evt:Event):void
{
    removeChild(playPart2);
    addChild(playPart3);
    playPart3.gotoAndPlay(1);
    var s3:Sound3 = new Sound3();
    s3.play();

}
```

My question is, I don't want to removeChild(playPart1);.  I want the child to stay. However - if I don't removeChild it, everything plays just fine.  If I do remove it, it seems as if it disregards the fact that it has to finish playGraph before moving onto playPart1.  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Can you edit this part please, it is confusing: *"I don't want to remove playPart1. However - if I don't remove it, everything plays just fine. If I do remove it, it seems as if it skips the Part1"*.

Comment: @sch56 why `playGraph.gotoAndPlay(1)` is outside `onCompleteGraph()`

Comment: It's there because I want to play the parts sequentially. Each event listener points to a new movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming Chart/Part1/Part2 are MovieClip symbols that dispatch the COMPLETE event when they reach the last frame? If that's correct, then I can take a reasonably good guess at what's happening.

You're making the assumption that your symbols will not play until you add them to the stage and call **gotoAndPlay**. This is incorrect, as soon as you instantiate a symbol it will begin playing in the background, that is, the first 4 lines of code will both create the symbol and begin playing them even though they're not visibly on the screen, as such, your COMPLETE events will fire in the background before you expect.

The solution is to stop these symbols from playing as soon as you instantiate them, and then begin playing once the previous COMPLETE event has fired.

```
var playGraph = new Chart();
var playPart1 = new Part1();
var playPart2 = new Part2();
var playPart3 = new Part3(); 

//Stop the symbols from playing automatically
playPart1.stop();
playPart2.stop();
playPart3.stop();

addChild(playGraph);
playGraph.gotoAndPlay(1);
var s1:SoundOne = new SoundOne();
s1.play();

playGraph.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteGraph); 
playPart1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompletePart1); 
playPart2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompletePart2); 

function onCompleteGraph(evt:Event):void
{
    playPart1.x = 370;
    playPart1.y = 190;
    addChild(playPart1);
    playPart1.gotoAndPlay(1);
}


function onCompletePart1(evt:Event):void
{

    playPart2.x = 100;
    playPart2.y = 100;
    addChild(playPart2);
    playPart2.gotoAndPlay(1);
    var s2:Sound2 = new Sound2();
    s2.play();

}

function onCompletePart2(evt:Event):void
{
    removeChild(playPart2);
    addChild(playPart3);
    playPart3.gotoAndPlay(1);
    var s3:Sound3 = new Sound3();
    s3.play();

}
```